# Потеря переменной в двойной конструкции switch

Tags: php, switch

Здравствуйте.

Есть "двухэтажная" конструкция switch

```
    switch ($p){
       default: 
         switch ($m){
           case 'some':
    // somecode
             $var = "foo";
           break;
    // somecode
         }
         break;
    //somecode
  }
```

В результате исолнения кода в `switch($m)` "теряются" переменные. Т.е. при дальнейшем их использовании они становятся null , хотя явно обозначаются как `$var = "foo"`

В чем может быть дело? Это нормальное поведение подобных конструкций или что? Ибо без нее в данном случае - никак.

Проблемная часть

```
case 'faq': 
     $title = " - F.A.Q";
      switch($_GET['mode']){ 
        default: 
          $title = "BRS F.A.Q"; 
         echo $tpl->result['head']; 
         break; 
         case 'auth_key': break; 
       } 
  break;
```

Теряется `$title`. Собственно в остальных случаях, где нет подконструкции, всё корректно исполняется.

Comment: Данный код у меня отрабатывает как надо. Приведите полный текст кода, может вы где-то в другом месте переменную обнуляете, либо у вас `$m` имеет значение, отличное от `some`

Comment: сделайте отладочный вывод `$m` перед `switch($m)` - скорее всего `case "some"` - не обрабатывается

Comment: @BOPOH
case 'faq':
 $title = " - F.A.Q";
  switch($_GET['mode']){
   default: 
   $title = "BRS F.A.Q";
   
   //echo $tpl->result['head'];
   
   break;

   case 'auth_key':

   break;
  }
 break;

Comment: @BOPOH перед switch через print значение переменной нормально выводит.

Comment: Вы вопрос отредактируйте, в комментариях не понятно ничего. Тем более опять только часть привели, а не все условие.

Comment: @BOPOH поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и не понял где и что у вас теряется. Вот несколько тестов:

```
function test($p, $m) {
    $title = 'default';
    switch ($p) {
        case 'faq':
            $title = " - F.A.Q";
            switch ($m) {
                default:
                    $title = "BRS F.A.Q";
                    break;
                case 'auth_key':
                    break;
            }
        break;
    }
    return $title;
}

echo test('faq', 'auth_key') . "\n";        // ' - F.A.Q'
echo test('faq ', 'auth_key') . "\n";       // 'default'
echo test('faq', 'auth_key2') . "\n";       // 'BRS F.A.Q'
echo test('faq2', 'auth_key') . "\n";       // 'default'
echo test('faq2', 'auth_key2') . "\n";      // 'default'
```

Все выводит как и ожидается, нигде ничего не теряется. Там, где выводит `default` - так и должно вводить, т.к. не срабатывает ни один `case`.

Соответственно, если вы где-то что-то потеряли, значит либо у вас где-то логика хромает, либо исходные данные не совпадают с вашими ожиданиями.